# Mac OS X automatic network disk mount after boot or login

Tags: macos, mac, samba

Every day I need to connect/mount an externel drive from a linux samba machine.
How can I setup Mac OS X (10.5.8 on a G5) to let him do this automatically after login or boot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is a network share just drag the mounted disk to the Login Items tab of the Accounts System Preference pane under the account of your user. The disk will then be automatically mounted on the next login.

Comment: perfect, this works fine

Comment: This has 2 problems: 1) it opens Finder and shows the contents of the network share when the user logs in, and 2) if the share goes away temporarily for any reason while the user is logged in it is never remounted. You can use automator to fix problem 1, but it won't fix 2. Create a script that mounts the drive and use launchd to run it to fix both. To mount a network drive in a script use "mount -t afp afp://@<backup_disk_name>.local/<share_name> /Volumes/<share_name>".

Answer (score 0):

Second hit on Google

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20031022164821984

Tried anything like that yet?

Comment: and where i have to put this urls?
sry but google wasn't helpful for me this time

Comment: As previously mentioned Google it is not acceptable answers on SU.