# How To Assign Drive Letter To Folder on Mac?

Tags: windows, mac, networking, hard-drive

I dont want to *mount* a folder or another drive using SMB in Mac OS X.  I want to *map* a folder or another drive like I can in Windows - using a drive letter.  When I map I can be sure that if the resource becomes unavailable, the mapping remains.  When a user tries to reconnect to an unavailable resource, Windows attempts to bring that resource back before it produces a resource unavailable failure.

I could be wrong but with my experience, using CMD-K and doing SMB://myresourcehere on my iMac results in a mount, but once the resource is turned off or resets or sleeps the mount has to be created again.

It COULD be something I am doing wrong and I would like to know if that is the case but also, I would like to know IF I can also simply assign a drive letter to a resource such as a folder on the network somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mac, based on it's unix-oid heritage (BSD/Darwin) knows of one hierarchical filesystem. What you would call "map a drive letter" on windows is done by "mounting" a drive/volume/remote link in this type of environment.

see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/77245/mac-os-x-automatic-network-disk-mount-after-boot-or-login) question here on superuser for more info.

Answer (score 3):

> I dont want to mount a folder or
>   another drive using SMB in Mac OS X. I
>   want to map a folder or another drive
>   like I can in Windows - using a drive
>   letter. When I map I can be sure that
>   if the resource becomes unavailable,
>   the mapping remains. When a user tries
>   to reconnect to an unavailable
>   resource, Windows attempts to bring
>   that resource back before it produces
>   a resource unavailable failure.

The quick answer here is.

***You can't.***

The Mac OS X does not know what a drive letter is, nor what do with it.  The reason Windows does that is a convulted mess, but...

> Drive letter assignment is the process
>   of assigning alphabetical identifiers
>   to physical or logical disk drives or
>   partitions (drive volumes) in the root
>   filesystem namespace; ***this usage is
>   now found only in Microsoft operating
>   systems.*** Unlike the concept of UNIX
>   mount points, where volumes are named
>   and located arbitrarily in a single
>   hierarchical namespace, drive letter
>   assignment allows multiple
>   highest-level namespaces. Drive letter
>   assignment is thus a process of using
>   letters to name the roots of the
>   "forest" representing the file system;
>   each volume holds an independent
>   "tree" (or, for non-hierarchical file
>   systems, an independent list of
>   files).

So, how can you reproduce this?  Well, using an automount would be fairly close to what you are asking...  But that requires editting the autofs file, and requires the username / password to be hard coded...

That's bad security...

So, as the answerer in the other page said...

> If it is a network share just drag the
>   mounted disk to the Login Items tab of
>   the Accounts System Preference pane
>   under the account of your user. The
>   disk will then be automatically
>   mounted on the next login.

Or, place a alias of the share on their desktop...  Have them click on that and it'll prompt for their credentials... And mount the share....

Or... This isn't quite the best way I would recommend to do it, but it'll work...

This is an apple script for Map Network Drive

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        mount volume "afp://username@server/directory_to_mount"
    end try
end tell
```

1. You have to save as application.
2. Set it run everytime you logon computer by Go to system preferences -> accounts -> Login item

Alternatively,

```
"GNARLODIOUS" is in (list disks) 
if the result is false then 
   mount volume "smb://hostname/sharename" as user name "Username" with password "password" 
end if 

on idle 
if "DISKNAME" is not in (list disks) then 
  mount volume "smb://hostname/sharename" as user name "username" with password "password" 
end if 
return 60 
end idle
```

Comment: I wish I could give two check-marks as answers.  You and @lexu have both enlightened me equally.   Thank you!